# Check Who I am following via Twitter4j

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

Is There anyway to check if I am following a certain user on Twitter other than getting the whole list of people who I am following and then start comparing Ids?

What I know is getting the whole list of people I am following is done through this method:

```
getFriendsIDs(long cursor) 
      Returns an array of numeric IDs for every user the authenticating user is following.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`showFriendship`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FriendshipMethods.html#showFriendship%28long,%20long%29) method to see if one user is following another.  Call that method, which returns a [`Relationship`](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/Relationship.html) object, which has methods to see if the two users specified are following each other.

Comment: Thanks! `showFriendship("source","target").isSourceFollowingTarget()`.